# Inserting open cv fuction and rotation image in the same window of tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to put these two functions in a tkinter window and displayed together:

```
import cv2

import tkinter as tk

from PIL import Image , ImageTk

root=tk.Tk()

def draw(self):
    image = Image.open(self.filename)

    angle = 0

    while True:

        for i in range(len(arr)):

            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))

            canvas_obj = self.Canvas1.create_image(
                250, 250, image=tkimage)

            self.master.after_idle(self.update)
            yield

            self.Canvas1.delete(canvas_obj)

            angle = arr[i]

            print(angle)

            time.sleep(.1)    

def cv():

    path = 'E:/Autopilot-TensorFlow-master/driving_dataset/'

    cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

    j = 0

    for j in range(10000):

        image_name = str(j) + '.jpg'

        image_path = path + image_name

        img = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)

        cv2.imshow('image', img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

            break
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask explains how you should ask a question for better answers. Instead of just posting the code you have, explain exactly what the problem is. It's hard for anyone to help you when all they have to go off of is a short title.

Comment: I want to make a GUI that have to frames .. the first Frame show image and it will be rotated .. the other frame will display a stream of images that displayed as a video ..